# Random game code id generator in typescript

Tags: javascript, random, typescript

Below is a simple typescript class used to generate a room code for an online lobby-based game (for example, https://jackbox.tv/ uses 4 digit codes to join rooms)

The goal of the class is to quickly generate *unique* 4-letter codes for game lobbies, and release them after the lobby is closed. Typically, less than 100 lobby codes will be used at once so using up all 26^4 codes will likely never happen.

Concerns:

- Is the method for generating codes efficient? Currently it just picks a random code and keeps incrementing until an unused code is found
- Is the method for encoding a number to an alphabet efficient? (converting a number to base 26)

```js
const ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

function randInt(min: number, max: number) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

export class RoomCodeManager {
  codeLength: number;
  usedCodes: Set<string>;
  // Generate 4-letter codes by default
  constructor(codeLength = 4) {
    this.codeLength = codeLength;
    this.usedCodes = new Set();
  }
  generateCode() {
    const min = 0;
    const max = Math.pow(ALPHABET.length, this.codeLength);
    let code = randInt(min, max);

    // If every code is already in use, just return a random code
    if (this.usedCodes.size >= max) {
      return this.encodeAlphabet(code);
    }

    // Keep incrementing by 1 until an unused code is found
    while (this.usedCodes.has(this.encodeAlphabet(code))) {
      code = (code + 1) % max;
    }
    this.usedCodes.add(this.encodeAlphabet(code));
    return this.encodeAlphabet(code);
  }
  encodeAlphabet(num: number) {
    let str = "";
    const len = ALPHABET.length;
    while (num > 0) {
      let radix = num % len;
      str = ALPHABET[radix] + str;
      num = Math.floor(num / len);
    }
    return str.padStart(this.codeLength, ALPHABET[0]);
  }
  releaseCode(code: string) {
    this.usedCodes.delete(code);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One important consideration: should those who do not have the code for a room be able to guess it (or guess a random code) and enter a room they were never told the code for? If not, then 4 characters probably isn't quite enough:

- If guesses and codes were random, the chance of guessing a lobby is on the order of magnitude of 100/450_000. Chances are low, but they're not astronomically low. To make it better, increase the number of characters in a code.
- But long random character strings are difficult to remember. If you think that might be a problem for the UI, consider using random *words* instead - for example, have a dictionary of a large number of English words, and then to generate a code, put two or three of them together.

> Is the method for generating codes efficient? Currently it just picks a random code and keeps incrementing until an unused code is found

If you really expect there to be less than 100 codes in use at a given time, then the chances of a collision are extremely low, so simply re-picking a random number in such rare cases sounds perfectly fine to me. If the app became more popular and collisions started happening on a regular basis, *then* it might be time to consider a different approach (such as hashing incremental numbers, or increasing the number of characters, or using a different algorithm entirely).

> Is the method for encoding a number to an alphabet efficient? (converting a number to base 26)

When turning a number into a string, I'd prefer to use `toString` if possible. For example, if you're able to use numbers 0-9 in addition to letters, you could make `encodeAlphabet` much simpler and use:

```
  encodeAlphabet(num) {
    return num.toString(36);
  }
```

(though, for such an approach to be user-friendly, you might also want to remove all characters that might get confused with each other, like `O` and `0`)

Another approach to consider - rather than generating a number and then turning it into a string, how about generating random *characters* and putting those into a string instead? No need to work with modulo and radix:

```
generateCode() {
  let code;
  do {
    code = this.getRandomCode();
  } while (this.usedCodes.has(code));
  this.usedCodes.add(code);
  return code;
}
getRandomCode() {
  return Array.from(
    { length: this.codeLength },
    () => String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 65)
  ).join('');
}
```

```js
const ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

function randInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

class RoomCodeManager {
  // Generate 4-letter codes by default
  constructor(codeLength = 4) {
    this.codeLength = codeLength;
    this.usedCodes = new Set();
  }
  generateCode() {
    let code;
    do {
      code = this.getRandomCode();
    } while (this.usedCodes.has(code));
    this.usedCodes.add(code);
    return code;
  }
  getRandomCode() {
    return Array.from(
      { length: this.codeLength },
      () => String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 65)
    ).join('');
  }
  releaseCode(code) {
    this.usedCodes.delete(code);
  }
}

const roomCodeManager = new RoomCodeManager();
console.log(roomCodeManager.generateCode());
```

Regarding

```
// If every code is already in use, just return a random code
if (this.usedCodes.size >= max) {
  return this.encodeAlphabet(code);
}
```

Maybe, in such a case, increment `this.codeLength` instead of returning a duplicate? (Though, this'll probably never happen)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is over-engineered in some ways. If all you need is a random 4-character code, the following should suffice:

```js
const generateCode = length => {
  return Array(length).fill('x').join('').replace(/x/g, () => {
    return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 65)
  })
}

console.log(generateCode(4))
```

JS has a function `String.fromCharCode()` that turns decimals into the equivalent character. You can look up an ascii table and see that A-Z is 65-90. No need to hardcode a string of letters.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 65
```

This piece generates a random digit from 65-90. What it does is take `Math.random()` (0-1, 1 not included), multiplies it by 26 (gives you 0-26, 26 not included), then offsets by 65 (gives 65-91, 91 not included).

You can keep calling the function until you find a unique random sequence. `string.replace()` can take a function that allows you to dynamically define a replacement. In our case, a random character form A-Z. The fill-join part is just a way to create a variable-length placeholder string, nothing special there.

Comment: `You can keep calling the function until you find a unique random sequence`

The purpose of the class was to encapsulate this process, the set keeps track of codes in use so that collisions don't occur

Comment: But your process of generating random codes is much more concise and doesn't depend on hard-coded variables which I like, thanks

Comment: @thesilican Yup, you'd call this inside your class. Your class will track collisions. Just so happened that I copy-pasted the `generateCode` name to my example snippet and made it confusing. :D